# Shell loop output date and number value to HTML

Tags: shell-script, shell, html

I have a tricky problem that requires mass generation of HTML in the following content format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<time>2020-10-01 07:46:13</time>
<p>text01</p>
</div>

<div>
<time>2020-10-02 07:46:13</time>
<p>text02</p>
</div>

more...

</body>
</html>
```

It needs to loop out two values.

- Date (in daily increments)
- Number (incremental from 01)

I need to generate roughly 100 , how do I do this?

Any help is appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might do the trick for you:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

cat << EOF
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

EOF

for ((i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)); do
cat << EOF
<div>
<time>$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -d "+${i} days")</time>
<p>$(printf "test%02d" "${i}")</p>
</div>

EOF

done


cat << EOF
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

It starts out by printing the stuff that doesn't change at the top of the file.  Next, it runs a loop from 1..100.  Each time through the loop, it generates one `div` block.  The time is the current time plus `i` days and the paragraph has `test` followed by `i` (padded with a single 0).  It wraps up by printing the stuff that doesn't change at the end of the file.

A sample run:

```
$ ./ex.sh
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<time>2020-10-17 22:57:00</time>
<p>test01</p>
</div>

<div>
<time>2020-10-18 22:57:00</time>
<p>test02</p>
</div>

...

<div>
<time>2021-01-23 21:57:01</time>
<p>test99</p>
</div>

<div>
<time>2021-01-24 21:57:01</time>
<p>test100</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's working. thank you. have a great day.